# CDockablePane prevent from closing

Tags: c++, mfc

Can I hide `close button` from `CDockablePane` and prevent it from closing?
I cannot find `CanBeClosed` method in the headers that I've just googled.
I suppose I can use `PreTranslateMessage` to filter `WM_CLOSE` event. But I am not sure that this is correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the dockable pane is really closed, AFAIK it is only hidden when the close button is pressed.

Note: WM_CLOSE is not send via a a PostMessage, it is directly delivered to the window.

There are several ways.

1. Handle OnClose (WM_CLOSE) yourself in your derived CDockablePane
2. The virtual function OnPressCloseButton is called. You migh overwrite it.
3. In your parent frame class (usually your CMainFrame) handle AFX_WM_ON_PRESS_CLOSE_BUTTON, you receive this message with the lParam set with the pointer to the CDockablePane. Return non zero to prevent closing.

I think method 3. is the one you should use...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of Visual Studio you have, but, that method is defined and implemented in AfxBasePane.h.  Since it's virtual, you need to override it to remove the button.  Details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983127(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to work with that method.